# How can I delete these internal line segments in Illustrator CS6 (intersection of circle and rectangle)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

X marks line segments I would like to remove.  At the end I would like to have one continuous shape.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Why is it not working? Showing some effort to solve the issue on your own goes a long way.

Comment: Hi Scott, do you know how to do this?  Did you downvote my question?  I tried Object>Path>Divide objects below.  I also tried Object>Compound Path>Make to make a compound path.  One solution to my question is a function that cuts all selected lines and curves at their intersection.

Comment: Yes I know how and yes I down voted. This question shows *no effort*. Simply asking for directions with *basic* operations is not a good question. You need to **show** what you have tried, where it fails and why.

Comment: Lame.  My criteria are clearly illustrated in the diagram.

Comment: It's not the criteria.. it's the *lack of effort* on your part. GraphicDesign.StackExchange.com is **not** a "tutorial on demand" site. (FYI.. Pathfinder has the answer. The sheer laziness to not explore Pathfinder more is another example of how little effort has been put into this question.)

Comment: Whatever man.  I probably have way more CAD experience than you. I will post the answer when I complete my effort.

Comment: errrm.. okay.. don't think anyone was referring to experience levels, but whatever you've got to tell yourself is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Select both of your 2 elements, open Pathinder (Window>Pathfinder) and click on the first one.
[image: Pathfinder]